# Getting 3rd line of div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

I have a div with some content in four lines. I am able to get number of lines by using the following code. But my requirement is to get 4 line text of the div. For example:

```
<div>
   ut returns between paragraphsut returns between paragraphs
   ut returns between paragraphsut returns between paragraphs
   web ui text is going on hereut returns between paragraphsut 
   returns between paragraphs
</div>
```

In the above DIV.I want to get 4th line text i.e., returns between paragraphs.Is there any way to do this.

I am getting number of lines with the following code

```
var content = elm.innerHTML;     
var elmHeight = elm.offsetHeight;
var lineHeight = 15;
var lines = elmHeight / lineHeight;
```

lines variable has number of lines in a particular DIV

Comment: number of lines might be different according to different screen size (width), for small screen you may get 8 lines, it depends on word wrapping, but if you sure that each line ends with line break (\n) you may work on it.

Comment: what code you tried to get the 4th line ...

Comment: If it has line-break character:

    `var fourth = $.trm($('div').text()).split('\n')[3];` http://jsfiddle.net/wg3U2/

Answer (score 0):

The following works in Firefox for me.  I hope it could be adopted to work under IE as well.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript">
<!--

function find3rdline (element)
{
    var text = element.textContent;

    var begin = -1;
    var end = -1;
    var top = -1;
    var line = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
        var id = "marker" + i;
        element.innerHTML = text.substr (0, i) + "<span id='" + id + "'>X</span>" + text.substr (i, text.length - i);
        var marker = document.getElementById (id);
        if (marker.offsetTop != top)
        {
            top = marker.offsetTop;
            line++;
            if (line == 2) begin = i;
            else if (line == 3)
            {
                end = i;
                // break;
            }
        }
    }

    element.innerHTML = text;

    if (begin == -1) return "";
    else if (end == -1) return text.substr (begin, text.length - begin);
    else return text.substr (begin, end - begin);
}

// -->
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="alert ('Third line is: [' + find3rdline (text) + ']')">
    <div id="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce porttitor, leo non sollicitudin blandit, metus eros dapibus massa, nec euismod nunc sapien quis nunc. Maecenas mollis, justo sed egestas semper, nulla libero blandit sem, eget gravida ante sapien sagittis turpis. Vivamus sit amet elit tortor, a eleifend mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum sit amet pellentesque magna. Integer eget erat nisl. Suspendisse adipiscing placerat felis quis blandit. Etiam hendrerit tincidunt gravida. Nunc condimentum tristique commodo. Aliquam eget tellus et sapien accumsan cursus.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce porttitor, leo non sollicitudin blandit, metus eros dapibus massa, nec euismod nunc sapien quis nunc. Maecenas mollis, justo sed egestas semper, nulla libero blandit sem, eget gravida ante sapien sagittis turpis. Vivamus sit amet elit tortor, a eleifend mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum sit amet pellentesque magna. Integer eget erat nisl. Suspendisse adipiscing placerat felis quis blandit. Etiam hendrerit tincidunt gravida. Nunc condimentum tristique commodo. Aliquam eget tellus et sapien accumsan cursus.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

var line_number=3; // The line number you prefer

var result= $.trm( $( '#mydiv' ).text() ).split( '\n' )[line_number];// mydiv is the id of division

alert(result);